# AJAX search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following search form from my html view and ajax code to handle the form request

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Ready');
    $('.search-wrapper').on('click', '#find-dates', function(a) {
      a.preventDefault();
      console.log('click');
      var t = $("#tour-id").val(),
        e = $("#travel-year").val(),
        o = $("#travel-month").val();
      console.log(t);
      console.log(e);
      console.log(o);
      $("#ajaxloader").show(), $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/trip/fetch-departures",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        },
        data: {
          tour_id: t,
          year: e,
          month: o
        },
        success: function(a) {
          $(".ajaxloadmoredeparture").html(a), $("#ajaxloader").hide()
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="uk-container-expand ">
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body ">
    <div uk-grid="" class="uk-child-width-1-4@m uk-child-width-1-1@s uk-grid-match uk-grid-small search-wrapper uk-grid">
      <div class="uk-first-column">
        <p>Please Check Available Dates for The Year:</p>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="tour-id">
      </div>
      <div>
        <select class="uk-select" id="travel-year">Select year
          <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select year</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select class="uk-select" id="travel-month">Select Month
          <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">Jun</option>
          <option value="7">Jul</option>
          <option value="8">Aug</option>
          <option value="9">Sep</option>
          <option value="10">Oct</option>
          <option value="11">Nov</option>
          <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="search-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" id="find-dates">Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above js code seems to be working fine in here. I can see datas of all 3 variables in the console. But in my development server 
the two variables returns null.

`console.log(e);
 console.log(o);`

I've indeed included jquery cdn link in my project file as well. 
I would be very thankful if anyone could drop some suggestion what I've been missing leading to this kind of error ?

Comment: might be the reason will your id is conflicting like 
`e = $("#travel-year").val()`
`o = $("#travel-month").val()`
check in the page for this two ids if you used this same id in your page and 
otherwise give the proper error what you are getting in console when you are running this

Comment: I don't think you can separate commands with a `,` like you did twice: `$("#ajaxloader").show(), $.ajax({` and  `$(".ajaxloadmoredeparture").html(a), $("#ajaxloader").hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`

See this:https://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Ready');
    $('.search-wrapper').on('click', '#find-dates', function(a) {
      a.preventDefault();
      console.log('click');
      var t = $("#tour-id").val(),
        e = $("#travel-year").val(),
        o = $("#travel-month").val();
      console.log(t);
      console.log(e);
      console.log(o);
      $("#ajaxloader").show(), $.getJSON({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/trip/fetch-departures",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        },
        data: {
          tour_id: t,
          year: e,
          month: o
        },
        success: function(a) {
          $(".ajaxloadmoredeparture").html(a), $("#ajaxloader").hide()
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="uk-container-expand ">
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body ">
    <div uk-grid="" class="uk-child-width-1-4@m uk-child-width-1-1@s uk-grid-match uk-grid-small search-wrapper uk-grid">
      <div class="uk-first-column">
        <p>Please Check Available Dates for The Year:</p>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="tour-id">
      </div>
      <div>
        <select class="uk-select" id="travel-year">Select year
          <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select year</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select class="uk-select" id="travel-month">Select Month
          <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">Jun</option>
          <option value="7">Jul</option>
          <option value="8">Aug</option>
          <option value="9">Sep</option>
          <option value="10">Oct</option>
          <option value="11">Nov</option>
          <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="search-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" id="find-dates">Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```